# Adding multiple ggplot2 lines within an if statement (without repeating the if statement)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add several ggplot lines (layers) within an if statement (without repeating the if statement?
Please see example data below:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, p = 1:5, q = factor(1:5),
                  r = factor(1:5))

# It works to have one line within if statement: 
ggplot(dat, aes(x, 
                y, 
                colour = p, 
                size = q, 
                shape = r)) +
  geom_point() +
  {
   if(TRUE) 
     guides(col=FALSE) 
  } +
  xlim(0, 10) +
  ylim(0, 10) +
  theme_classic()


# Adding more lines WITHIN the if statement does NOT work:
ggplot(dat, aes(x, 
                y, 
                colour = p, 
                size = q, 
                shape = r)) +
  geom_point() +
  {
    if(TRUE) 
      guides(col=FALSE) +
      xlim(0, 10) +
      ylim(0, 10) 
  } +
  theme_classic()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, 
                y, 
                colour = p, 
                size = q, 
                shape = r)) +
  geom_point() +
  {
    if(TRUE) 
      list(
        guides(col="none"),
        xlim(0, 10),
        ylim(0, 10)
      )
  }
```

(Note, since ggplot2 3.3.4, guides should use `"none"` instead of `FALSE`.)

[image]